# How can I make the URL not add # and the ID when I go to an anchor

Tags: html

I have a piece of code

`<li><a href="#two" class="button" id="Button123">Text</a></li>`

When I click this, my page goes down to

`<section id="two" class="wrapper style3 fade-up twoSection">`

Which is good, but now the url has

> /#two

added onto it, how can I prevent the id being added to the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to manually scroll (check [Element.scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method) document and also prevent default. Maybe something like this:

```
document.querySelector('#Button123').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/aFiE3GrlSb9MiK5qLeeY?p=preview

Comment: The link you put up has expired.